# If $tr. deg. F/K=r$ then $tr.deg. F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)/K(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=r$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, transcendence-degree

Let $F/K$ be a field extension of transcendence degree $r$ and let $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ be a set of elements which are algebraically independent over $K$. Then is it true that $tr.deg. F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)/K(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=r$?

If $\{t_1,\ldots,t_r\}$ is a transcendence base of the extension $F/K$ then we know $F/K(t_1,\ldots,t_r)$ is algebraic and $K(t_1,\ldots,t_r)/K$ is purely transcendental. Thus $F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)/K(x_1,\ldots,x_n)(t_1,\ldots,t_r)$ is also algebraic. Now it will be enough to show that $\{t_1,\ldots,t_r\}$ is algebraically independent over $K(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. How should I approach?

My above queries are from the book of Lang's Algebra book in the context of being free from one field to another.
I have added a photo from Lang's Algebra book: I want to understand why $tr. deg. F(y)/K(y)=r$ as shown in the diagram.

[image]

Comment: As written, $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ are merely algebraically independent over $K$, hence they might be the same as $\{t_1,\ldots,t_r\}$, making the claim false.

Comment: What Hagen said. You need $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ to be algebraically independent over $F$ to guarantee this.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I have added a screenshot of the context of my queries.

Comment: The screenshot is missing something essential. What are $K$ and $k$ there? Also, apparently $F$ is not a random extension field but something dependent on the context. The original version of your question made it look like the claim is made for *an arbitrary extension $F$*, which is why Hagen von Eitzen and I protested.

Comment: For example, the excerpt says that $F$ is **a subfield** of $K$, and the claim is about $F(y)/k(y)$ rather than $F(y)/K(y)$. In other words, your question, as it is currently phrased, does not match the excerpt at all. This may be the source of your misunderstanding of the presentation.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen More context is given now for your reference, which is at $362$ th page of Langs Algebra book.

Comment: I don't own a copy of Lang, and lockdown makes it difficult to reach the library. However, the current excerpt allows an interpretation of the question. I hope my answer addresses your concern. Do read more carefully! Lang says nothing about $F(y)/K(y)$, it's $F(y)/k(y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, it is about why the extension $F(y)/k(y)$ described in the excerpt has transcendence degree $r$.

---

This follows from the assumptions made in that claim. Let $(t):=\{t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_r\}$ be a transcendence basis of $F/k$. Then $(t)$ is a subset of $K$ that is algebraically independent over the base field $k$. Because $K$ was assumed to be free from $L$ over $k$, it follows that $(t)$ remains algebraically independent over $L$. Therefore $(t)$ is also algebraically independent over the subfield $k(y)\subseteq L$. Therefore the transcendence degree of $F(y)/k(y)$ is at least $r$. Because $F(y)$ is algebraic over $k(y)(t)$ the transcendence degree cannot be higher. Hence the transcendence degree of $F(y)/k(y)$ is exactly $r$ as the diagram claims.

---

The assumption of freeness of $K$ from $L$ is absolutely essential in this argument, and the claim may be false otherwise.

In the prescribed context $F$ is a subfield of $K$, so the title question is a bit strange.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I can’t make a general statement like what i made earlier. One has to use the fact $K$ is free from $L$ over $k$.

Comment: @user371231 Yeah. I recall details like this keeping me on my toes the first time I read about it. Lang makes the analogy with linearly disjoint extension. IIRC I only learned about those later, but it makes great pedagogical sense to draw attention to the analogy. Easier not to drop the ball when keeping that in mind.

Comment: I am  curious to know what is the meaning of IIRC?

Comment: @user371231: If I Recall / Remember Correctly.